# undefined local variable or method `venues_path'

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rspec-rails

I'm using Michael Hartl's tutorial to write my own app.  I have the following test.  I noticed Hartl `require 'spec_helper'` while the pending RSpec files created by RSpec install `require 'rails_helper'`.  I have

```
resources :venues
```

But I still get the error that venues_path is undefined when I run rspec.  The following is defined inside spec/requests.

```
require 'spec_helper'

RSpec.describe Venue, type: :model do
  subject { page }

  describe 'index page' do
    let(:venue) { FactoryGirl.create(:venue) }
    before { visit venues_path }

    it { should have_content(venue.name) }
  end
end
```